# capturar por grupos los valores de los atributos option regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Tengo esta expresión regular `<option\s?(value="(.+?)?")?\s?(selected="selected")?>(.+?)<\/option>`
 validando en el contenido de una página las etiquetas option de un select que se crean dinámicamente. Necesito capturar el valor si lo tiene, saber si tiene el attributo *selected*.

Como ejemplo tengo estas opciones:

```
<option value="">opcion 1</option>
<option value="opcion2check">opcion 2</option>
<option value="" selected="selected">--Ninguno--</option>
```

Con las 2 primeras opciones funciona correctamente. Con la última existe al parecer un problema con un espacio, por lo que no toma el valor como `null` y en cambio devuelve `" selected="selected` como valor en el attributo *value*.
Aqui el [link](https://regexr.com/3h6hm) donde estoy probrando la expresión.

Comment: Si te sirvió alguna de las respuestas te invito a que marques la respuesta como aceptada, para que otros desarrolladores sepan cual fue la solución. Gracias :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ese es el problema de intentar procesar HTML con regex. Siempre hay una excepción que va a romper tu patrón, ya que no hay chances de que pongas toda la sintaxis de HTML en un solo regex (teóricamente sí, pero al menos no dentro de lo lógico).

**El error** sucede porque el `.+?`, si bien intenta consumir cuantos menos caracteres puede, intenta coincidir con al menos 1 caracter.

```
<option\s?(value="(.+?)?")?\s?(selected="selected")?>(.+?)<\/option>
                   ^^^
               acá consume el texto: " selected="selected
```

Entonces, como se encuentra con el texto

```
<option value="" selected="selected"
               |
               |
        El cursor del intento de coincidencia empieza acá
        .+? Primero intenta coincidir con 1 caracter (las comillas de cierre)
        pero no coincide el resto
        Entonces luego con 2 caracteres, y con 3, y con 4, etc.
```

Hasta que finalmente encuentra una coincidencia consumiendo:

```
<option value="" selected="selected">--Ninguno--</option>
               \___________________/
                      .+?
                coincide con este texto
```

Podrías pensar que el `?` exterior lo hace opcional, pero aún así, ese cuantificador es goloso (*greedy*), e intenta primero coincidir con una repetición antes de intentar con cero.

```
<option\s?(value="(.+?)?")?\s?(selected="selected")?>(.+?)<\/option>
                  ^^^^^^
               este cuantificador intenta coincidir primero con 1 repetición
```

---

**La solución sencilla** sería decirte que cambies el cuantificador `+` por `*`, quedando:

```
<option\s?(value="(.*?)")?\s?(selected="selected")?>(.*?)<\/option>
```

E incluso que simplificar un poco la expresión, sin crear grupos que probablemente no uses:

```
<option\s*(?:value\s*=\s*"(.*?)"\s*)?(selected\s*=\s*"selected"\s*)?>(.*?)<\/option>
```

O sin permitir comillas dentro de las comillas:

```
<option\s*(?:value\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"\s*)?(selected\s*=\s*"selected"\s*)?>(.*?)<\/option>
```

Pero eso aún va a fallar en muchos casos, como cualquier intento de este estilo de procesar HTML con regex.

Estos son algunos ejemplos de casos que harían fallar este patrón, o similares a este:

- Estás usando `.*?` para el contenido del `<option/>`. ¿Qué pasa si el contenido ocupa más de una línea?
- ¿Y si esto fuese parte del código JavaScript de tu página?

  ```
  <script>
      var rompeRegex = "<option>que no es parte de la página</option>";
  </script>
  ```
- ¿Y si hubiese un comentario del estilo:

  ```
  <option> Texto <!-- y este es el último </option> --> de la opción </option>
  ```
- Y la lista sigue, y sigue, y sigue

---

**La solución efectiva**. Estás programando en JavaScript, un lenguaje que está especialmente diseñado para lidiar con HTML. Usá las herramientas del lenguaje, y procesá el HTML con DOM, como se debe.

Hay 2 opciones principales dentro de JavaScript:

1. Sencilla pero insegura.

   Podés cargar el html dentro de la página actual (en un div oculto por ejemplo), y procesarlo como si estuvieras procesando tu propia página.
2. Usar [DOMImplementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation).

   De esta forma, crearías un modelo de documento que no está asociado a tu página.

Como comentaste luego que el objetivo es usarlo con Apex, mi respuesta sigue siendo la misma, con un Modelo de Objetos del Documento (DOM).

1. En Apex: ver [Dom Namespace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_namespace_Dom.htm).

Comment: Realmente la expresión la usaré en código Apex, pero para pruebas la estoy realizando en JavaScript

Comment: @XtheblackX Antes que nada, deberías etiquetar la pregunta como [tag:apex], o a lo sumo como [tag:java]. Apex usa el motor de Java para expresiones regulares, que difiere muchísimo de JavaScript. No vas a tener diferencias con el regex que estás usando, pero no estás muy lejos de encontrarlas.

Comment: @XtheblackX Y, mi respuesta sería exactamente la misma: en vez de quebrarte la cabeza con una expresión regular, Apex puede generar un DOM. Ver https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_namespace_Dom.htm

Answer (score 1):

Debes cambiar tu expresión regular a lo siguiente:

`<option\s?(value="([^"]+?)?")?\s?(selected="selected")?>(.+?)<\/option>`

la parte de la expresión. `[^"]` captura todo menos el caracter comilla doble `"`.

El caracter que denota el inicio de un string `^` cuando se usa entre corchetes `[^]` es una negación.

aquí el link con la prueba:

https://regex101.com/r/MMdySd/1

Answer (score -3):

Salvo casos puntuales, tratar de aplicar REGEX para parsear HTML es una contradicción.

Ver [la mejor respuesta al respecto que existe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZ2e3.png) y es legendaria en Stack Overflow.

> HTML is a Chomsky Type 2 grammar
>   (context free grammar) and RegEx is a Chomsky Type 3 grammar (regular
>   grammar). Since a Type 2 grammar is fundamentally more complex than a
>   Type 3 grammar (see the Chomsky hierarchy), you can't possibly make
>   this work. But many will try, some will claim success and others will
>   find the fault and totally mess you up.

Incluso hay un meme que circula por internet

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]